# how do i write EPS and postScript programs?

Tags: scripts, ghostscript, postscript

I am trying to write EPS scripts.

```
%!
100 100 moveto
/Symbol 12 selectfont (p ) show
/Times-Roman 12 selectfont (is less than 4) show
```

I suspect that beginning the script with %! is not correct, or sufficient.
Unfortunately, I cannot find recent documentation, so I am unsure what eps scripts begin with.

Comment: You could argue that the question could be reworded to: "How do I write EPS and PostScript programs on Ubuntu?". As this was ask for in the Ubuntu form - I answered what was needed to do it on that platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the above lines in a file 'program.eps' and run the following command

```
evince program.eps
```

Evince will open up and render 'program.eps'. If you are missing 'evince' install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install evince
```

Comment: Cool! That works better than GhostView.